# install python 3.6 in colab

Tags: python, conda, google-colaboratory

I am using a repository which was created in Python 3.6. I wanted to run it in my Colab but it seems to be impossible to install python 3.6 in Colab!

I have searched all the web and no correct answer was found :(

It's possible to use conda and create env with python 3.6 in it.(like below)

```
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-py38_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh
!./Miniconda3-py38_4.8.2-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!conda update conda -y
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
!conda create -n myEnv python=3.6 -y
```

Then I can install packages in python 3.6,

```
%%shell
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate myEnv
python --version
pip install -r /content/TransVisDrone/requirements.txt
```

but when I want to run the .py file it won't use conda env :(

```
!conda activate myEnv && python  /content/python.py
```

Help me please, I have to finish this work as fast as possible and my pc is too slow for it.

**edit1**:
ever thing looks fine using `!conda run -n myEnv python  /content/python.py`

Comment: Does `!conda run -n myEnv python  /content/python.py` work?

Answer (score -3):

Just use `conda activate myenv` and it's done.

Comment: thanks for the answer... I have checked it before and it wont activate myenv! saying use init and not working with init to :|