# Real-time output with Conda environment on Colab

Tags: python, conda, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I installed Python 3.8 on Google Colab, so I can create an environment using Python 3.6 (as I wasn't able to directly install Python 3.6). I have done it exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77292961/install-python-3-6-in-colab), and in order to use python 3.6, I can either use this:

```py
!conda run -n myEnv python main.py
```

Or I can execute a chunk of code using this:

```py
%%bash
source activate myEnv
python

import time

print("OK")
time.sleep(10)
print("OK")
```

Unfortunately, in both of these, the output of conda will not be in real-time. So, the output of the code will only be shown after full execution of the code/file. For example, the chunk I have mentioned will only output after 10 seconds with:

```
OK
OK
```

How can I make it real-time output directly to Google Colab? so I can see the first `OK` and then wait 10 seconds before the second `OK` is given. Is it even possible?

If it's not possible, then maybe a workaround to output to any other place that I can at least see it in real-time, for example, changing the `print` function to output to a file (but that wouldn't be ideal as I need to always refresh and open the file in Colab, but better than nothing).

**EDIT #1:**

I tried these but nothing works:

1. `sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering/107717#107717)
2. Using `-u` flag `!conda run -n myEnv python -u main.py`
3. Using `print("OK", flush=True)`
4. Using `sys.stdout.flush()`
5. Using `!conda run -n myEnv python main.py --live-stream`

But mocking the `sys.stdout.write` does work with:

```py
import sys

def mock_write(text):
    with open("out.txt", "a") as fh:
        fh.write(text)
    real_write = type(sys.stdout).write
    real_write(sys.stdout, text)

sys.stdout.write = mock_write
```

I can see the output in the file `out.txt` before the execution finishes, but I would have to always refresh my drive in order to see the new file. Any way to make it even better? maybe to a local page that I can see the output from?

Comment: Have you tried the `--live-stream` option in `conda run`? If that doesn't work, it sounds more generally like a Jupyter-bash buffering problem (nothing to do with Colab or Conda specifically).

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, any workarounds for that?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/107717/9703451

Comment: Nothing seems to be working, it's like everything is happening in Jupyter and will never come to Colab unless it finishes.

Comment: Please edit the question to include variants you have tried.